# GridView Custom Paging - First, Last, Next, Previous,Numeric

Tags: asp.net

I am using a sql store procedure for custom paging.

Now i want to make a custom pager for gridview.

I have searched on google and find various articles about it.

But i am not getting which i want.

please help me for it if you have any idea about it.

Thanks,
Rajbir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you looking for something like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled = '<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick = "Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You will find more form [Custom Paging in ASP.Net GridView using SQL Server Stored Procedure](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing to do with Stored Procedure to use Paging in Gridview. Only you need to do is to bind your GridView on OnPageIndexChanging event.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{            
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;                     
}
```

Please visit this link for example: [ASP.NET GridView with Custom Paging UI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=339)

Comment: Actually i am fetching only the required records which are needed to display in gridview by my stored procedure. If i have 1,00,000 records in my database and i want to show only 10 in my gridview then why i will bind 1,00,000 records my gridview. So i have need custom paging. You are telling about the just inbuilt paging of gridview.

Comment: the person huMpty duMpty given your answer.